# Convert pandas multiindex into simple flat index of column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
        ('A', 'cat', 'long'), ('A', 'cat', 'long2'),
        ('A', 'dog', 'short'), ('B', 'dog', 'short')
    ],
    names=['exp', 'animal', 'hair_length']
)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4), columns=columns, index=['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'])
```

Which results in this structure:

```
exp                 A                             B
animal            cat                 dog       dog
hair_length      long     long2  short     short
W            1.088097 -0.104486  2.574262 -0.614482
X           -0.088731  0.620010  0.101627 -0.518250
Y           -0.687172  0.108860 -1.932803  1.104636
Z            2.453511  0.947065 -2.144457  1.036991
```

I now need to "flatten" the column structure into a simple list of column names, such as A_cat_long, A_dog_short and so on.

The following command seems to work:

```
df.columns = [ '_'.join(x) for x in df.columns ]

   A_cat_long  A_cat_long2  A_dog_short  B_dog_short
W   -0.968703     0.086291    -0.255741     1.487564
X    2.113484    -0.118909     0.698032    -0.058647
Y    0.822555     0.483175     1.221687     0.759047
Z   -1.260217     1.620935     0.417836     1.581388
```

Can anybody confirm whether this is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Seems fine to me and that's what I would do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anybody else comes across this - this indeed seems to do the trick:

```
df.columns = [ '_'.join(x) for x in df.columns ]
```

Result:

```
   A_cat_long  A_cat_long2  A_dog_short  B_dog_short
W   -0.968703     0.086291    -0.255741     1.487564
X    2.113484    -0.118909     0.698032    -0.058647
Y    0.822555     0.483175     1.221687     0.759047
Z   -1.260217     1.620935     0.417836     1.581388
```

Comment: You should separate your question and your answer. This one-line answer doesn't make sense: re-write your answer as if you didn't know the answer, and then answer it here, it'll be better